# How to get the Facebook photo using SocialOath?

Tags: android, facebook

Hello Friends,
              I am using the `SocailOath` to connect with `Facebook` and want to get the photo from `Facebook album`..I used the below code to get the Photo from the `Facebook`..And i am not getting any crash in my application...My problem is only that i am not getting the `Facebook album` photo..If there any grammatical error in my question than please pardon me..Thanks in Advance

```
package com.tv.socail;
import java.util.List;
import org.brickred.socialauth.Album;
import org.brickred.socialauth.Photo;
import org.brickred.socialauth.Profile;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.DialogListener;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter.Provider;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthError;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.tv.sociallogin.R;

public class Logins extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button fbConnect = null;

String socialId="";
String socialType="";
private String providerName;
private static SocialAuthAdapter adapter;

private final Provider[] providers = new Provider[] { Provider.FACEBOOK,
        Provider.TWITTER, Provider.LINKEDIN, Provider.GOOGLEPLUS };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.logins);

    fbConnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fbConnect);

    fbConnect.setOnClickListener(this);


    adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());



}


private final class ResponseListener implements DialogListener {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Successful");




        // Get the provider
        providerName = values.getString(SocialAuthAdapter.PROVIDER);

        Log.d("Custom-UI", "providername = " + providerName);

        // Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, providerName + " connected",
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        int res = getResources().getIdentifier(providerName + "_array",
                "array", Logins.this.getPackageName());
        //adapter.getUserProfileAsync(new ProfileDataListener());
        adapter.getAlbumsAsync(new AlbumDataListener()); 


    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError error) {
        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Error");
        error.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Cancelled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBack() {
        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Dialog Closed by pressing Back Key");

    }
}


private final class ProfileDataListener implements
 SocialAuthListener<Profile> {

    @Override
    public void onExecute(String provider, Profile t) {

        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Receiving Data");

        Profile profileMap = t;

        //String emailId=profileMap.getEmail();
        socialId=profileMap.getValidatedId();
        socialType=profileMap.getProviderId();


    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError e) {

    }
}

private final  class AlbumDataListener implements  SocialAuthListener<List<Album>>
{

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("I AM eroor");
    }

    @Override
    public void onExecute(String arg0,List<Album> t) {

        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Receiving Data");
        List<Album> albumList = t;

        System.out.println("I AM OUSIDE"+t.size());// HERE I AM GETTING THE ALBUM SIZE IS ZERO..

        if (albumList != null && albumList.size() > 0) {

            System.out.println("I AM INSIDE"+t.size());
            // Get Photos inside Album

            for (Album a : albumList) {
                Log.d("Custom-UI", "Album ID = " + a.getId());
                Log.d("Custom-UI", "Album Name = " + a.getName());
                Log.d("Custom-UI", "Cover Photo = " + a.getCoverPhoto());
                Log.d("Custom-UI", "Photos Count = " + a.getPhotosCount());

                List<Photo>photosList = a.getPhotos();

                if (photosList != null && photosList.size() > 0) {

                    for (Photo p : photosList) {

                        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Photo ID = " + p.getId());
                        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Name    = " + p.getTitle());
                        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Thumb Image =" + p.getThumbImage());
                        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Small Image =" + p.getSmallImage());
                        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Medium Image =" + p.getMediumImage());
                        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Large Image = " + p.getLargeImage());
                    }}
            }}
    }


}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.fbConnect:

        // This method will enable the selected provider
        try {
            adapter = null;
            adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());


            adapter.addConfig(Provider.FACEBOOK, "491810545445454972737",
                    "09897721dsde61b45545454545495fa22869096da63d2ef", null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        adapter.authorize(Logins.this, Provider.FACEBOOK);

        break;

    default:
        break;
     }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using social auth then you have to pass **permission** Parameter in addConfigue() Method. like for fetching the album of user then you have to pass parameter like **user_photos**

In yours code Replace **null**

```
 adapter.addConfig(Provider.FACEBOOK, "4918105455190xxxxxx",
                "09897721dsde61b95fa22869096dxxxxxx", null);
```

**to**

```
 adapter.addConfig(Provider.FACEBOOK, "4918105455190xxxxxx",
                "09897721dsde61b95fa22869096dxxxxxx", "user_photos");
```

Same for the **publish_actions** put these also in the place of null

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha .....Please check my solution..And mark right if it is workable for you..

Answer (score 1):

Have you requested the `user_photos` permission upon Facebook Login?

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: NO bro...Can you please tell me in brief??

Comment: How should this even work then. Read the docs "bro", the links are in my answer.

Comment: I am following these link to get the photos of facebook album
http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/part-1-using-socialauth-to-integrate-facebook-api-in-android